# Countdown timer in Excel UserForm doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have two identical workbooks, each containing a UserForm. The UserForms launch on opening the workbooks. Each UserForm contains a countdown timer, the code of which is given below. I need the UserForms such that when I click a *Submit* button on *UserForm1*, the *WorkBook1* (and *UserForm1*) should close and *WorkBook2* (and *UserForm2*) should open.

This is the code in SubmitButton_Click():

```
Workbooks.Open "WorkBook2.xlsm"
ThisWorkbook.Close True
```

I have set the *ShowModal* property of the UserForms to *False*, so they are modeless.

Code for countdown timer:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim T, E, M As Double, S As Double
Const AllowedTime As Double = 50 ' Countdown time in minutes

T = Timer
Do
    E = CDbl(Time) * 24 * 60 * 60 - T
    M = AllowedTime - 1 - Int(E / 60)
    S = 59 - Round((E / 60 - Int(E / 60)) * 60, 0)

    TimeLabel.Caption = Format(CStr(M), "00") & ":" & Format(CStr(S), "00")

    DoEvents
Loop Until (Timer - T) / 60 >= AllowedTime

Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

The timer works perfectly in *UserForm1*. Whenever I click the *Submit* button, *WorkBook2* opens up and shows the *UserForm2*, but the timer doesn't run (it just stands still at 50:00). Also, I noticed that when I manually close the *UserForm1*, the VBA editor shows that the form is still running. I have to manually press the Reset button every time.

The code for timer was taken from an Excel forum. I am fairly new to Excel and VBA, so I don't know exactly how it works. Anyway, I found that whenever the form is closed/unloaded, the code is paused at DoEvents. The form stops completely only when I press the Reset button in the VBA editor.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to fix the timer? Thank you.

Comment: At first glance I'd say `Unload UserForm1` in the activate event of `userform1`  will give you trouble.

Comment: This is happening because when you open userform2 in modal, the code execution stops and will continue only when the userform2 closes. Open the userform2 in vbmodeless and you will not face this problem `userform2 .show vbmodeless`

Comment: @Storax I tried removing `Unload UserForm1`, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the OP wants to close `Userform1` after a certain amount of time. As the post does not really tell how  `userform1` is opened I suggest to test the following code:
This code in a normal module

```
Option Explicit
Dim frm As UserForm1
Sub KillUserForm()
    Unload frm
End Sub
Sub Test()

    Set frm = New UserForm1
    Load frm
    frm.Show
    
End Sub
```

In the code of userform you now replace the line `Unload UserForm1` with `KillUserForm`.

Comment: I have edited the question, to make it more specific.